# Macbook pro dual external display

Tags: macos, display, macbook-pro

How can I connect two external DVI displays to a 13" MacBook Pro?

Comment: Note: shopping recommendations are _usually_ off topic, but because you're asking about _how_ to do it rather than _what specific item to buy_, this question is OK. I did edit it slightly to be less of a shopping recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One DVI display, one USB display. 13" MBPs all came with integrated graphics, none of which can handle two monitors over even a Thunderbolt port.